# Is it possible to prove that a function doesn't have an antiderivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, contour-integration, gaussian-integral

Consider the integral $\int f(x)\, dx$ where $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, it has been proven that there is no antiderivative made from elementary functions, but is there a way to prove that there is not such integral
$$\int (g(x(t),y(t))) · r'(t) dt = \int f(x) dx$$
for some appropriate function $g(x,y)$ and some appropriate curve $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$? If it is possible, then maybe $r'(t)$ could help with a $u$-sub, to find an antiderivative?

Comment: I don't see what you mean with $\int (f(x(t),y(t))) · r'(t)\, dt = \int f(x)\, dx$. Note the Fourier transform of the Gaussian gives $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- t^2} \frac{e^{-2i a t}-e^{-2i x t}}{2it} dt  = \sqrt{2\pi}\int_a^{x}  e^{-y^2}dy$.

Comment: Is there a way basically to prove there is no line integral on some curve c, under some function f(x,y) where it doesn't evaluate to exactly the Gaussian? Or is it even impossible for a surface to have some projection onto a plane or other surface where, the projection is the Gaussian integral. I'm trying to think of multivariable options we have to integrate the Gaussian, besides the standard polar transform. I want to understand the nature of how there is no elementry function which can be defined as the Gaussian.

Comment: @ClarkThomas36 I've edited a bit your question (and added a tag) to make it a bit clearer, because some people don't seem to understand you very well. I hope I didn't change the meaning; if I did, feel free to rollback or re-edit the question.

Comment: Check out the Risch algorithm.

Comment: Thank you Arnaud! @BobaFret I've looked at an article about it, but I wasn't sure if it would extend past basic anti differentiation. I thought that with all the choices of path, and all the possible surfaces, there might exist a line integral which would evaluate to the same?